# jquery serialize using a "®" instead of a "&" symbole

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a registration form that just suddenly stopped working and I don't know why but suddenly it's using a registration trademark symbol instead of the & symbol for the next field to be sent...

So I'm getting

```
?email=t%40t.com&country=43&password=something&province=37&confirmpassword=something*&city=11750&fname=g&phone=(416)377-3900&lname=g&terms=1®Form_captcha_text=NH8UG
```

instead of

```
?email=t%40t.com&country=43&password=something&province=37&confirmpassword=something*&city=11750&fname=g&phone=(416)377-3900&lname=g&terms=1&Form_captcha_text=NH8UG
```

I tried fixing this using a string replace but it's not catching it, anyone have any ideas why this would be happening, it works fine with the mobile form for some reason...

Comment: You haven't specified how you build the querystring, but you need to URI encode the property values using `encodeURIComponent()`. More info at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Comment: I'm simply using $('#form').serialize() which from what I understood should encode the form elements...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look at the component that does the captcha (see if it has a new version). From your query string, that is the only part that is different.

---

Also, do look for the text `reg;` or `reg` in your HTML, looks like the & is getting prepended to it making it the trademark symbol.

Comment: It's a custom captcha that's on both the mobile form and desktop version, I don't think this is the problem because it's only a textfield that's being read by the serialization which is text entered by the user...

Comment: I am using post, I'm using code to retrieve what it's sending though so that I could see it...

Comment: Look for the text reg; or reg in your HTML, looks like the & is getting prepended to it making it the trademark symbol.

Comment: I think you got it the fields name actually starts of with reg but there's no semicolon and only part of the name is being read... I'll change that and am pretty certain that's the problem...

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in your header if you haven't already

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

This has to do something with ISO-standards. If someone could explain this, please do.

Comment: I already have that deceleration in the page, I just double checked to make sure...